# Error: Record cannot be modified right now .This cron task is currently being executed and may not be modified, please try again in a few minutes

Tags: odoo

While configuring incoming mail server in OpenERP 7, i get this following error.

> Error: Record cannot be modified right now .This cron task is
>   currently being executed and may not be modified, please try again in
>   a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If the job keeps running, you won't get a chance to change the configuration of the cron job. I met same issue, and find a way to solve it.

There is a DB lock on that row.

If you run following sql query to check current processes:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where query like '%ir_cron%';
```

You can see some query like this (in the query field of the result):

```
select * from ir_cron where id = 100 for update nowait;
```

Get the **pid** from the query result, and terminate it with **PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND**. It will come back soon, so it's better to do the terminating and updating in one query, such as:

```
update ir_cron set active = false where PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND(57078) and id = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the scheduler for fetching mail to inactive.Its time gap is 5mins. So make it inactive. then edit the incoming mail server.

Comment: I can't even inactive the scheduler as the same error appears when i try to do that!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that original asker may not be interested anymore but for the sake of others :-

I faced the same error, while updating a module being developed.
So, the cron job related to my module had to be manually deleted first from the scheduler.

Settings -> Scheduler -> Scheduler Actions

delete the cron job you were trying to modify.
And update the module again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that kept me from upgrading a module.  I solved it by stopping the odoo server and restarting postgresql and then starting odoo again.  This gave me time to both mark the cron job as inactive and upgrade the module.

`sudo service odoo-server stop`
`sudo service postgresql restart`
`sudo service odoo-server start`